# Android kotlin - Navhost fragment - Popupto from menu

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am working on Android and I want to reset the navigate back to a intro fragment from anywhere in my application from a drawer menu item.

I saw the popupto option from an action in a fragment but I don't know how to use it in the menu item or even if it possible. May be this is not the right approach, I just want to be able to reset the stack and go back to a defined fragment from a click on a item menu.

Thx
Regards.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation on tying navigation to a menu item](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake what is the best way to clear the backStack? reset the navGraph or pop up to start destination?

Comment: Popping up to the start destination before navigating to your chosen destination is what `onNavDestinationSelected()` does already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after re reading the url from where I get the solution, it should clear the stack so my answer is this :

```
fun navigateFirstTabWithClearStack() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_main)
        val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_main) as NavHostFragment
        val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
        val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph_main)
        graph.startDestination = R.id.nav_graph_tab1

        navController.graph = graph
}
```

Solution from : https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/767

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snippet when menuItem Clicked

```
navController.popBackStack(navController.graph.startDestination,false)
```

for any case use this code snippet for pop up to some fragment

```
val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.popUpToFragmentId, true).build()
navController.navigate(R.id.destinationFragmentId, navOptions)
```

Comment: it works but it only work when we want to go back to the startDestination.

Comment: @QuentinM i edited the answer please test it hope this hepls

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that the id of the menu item matches the id of the chosen destination and then call:

```
// Tie all menu items in the drawer to their respective destinations
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)
```

or

```
// tie only the given item to a destination
val menuItem = navView.menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item)
NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController)
```

clearing the backStack before navigating to your chosen destination is the default behavior unless the menu item has `menuCategory="secondary"`.

Comment: R.id.destination do not work I need a NavDirections or URI. Do you know how can I convert it ?

Comment: sorry, i missed an argument. Just pass null as second argument

Comment: edit your question and show the implementation

Comment: Thx but I have an error :
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination small.app.projetmanage:id/fragment_nav cannot be found from the current destination Destination(small.app.projetmanage:id/mainFragment) label=fragment_main class=small.app.projetmanage.MainFragment
From what I understood I need to link my destination from my current fragment, is that true ? Cause if so I can not use that.

Comment: I aslo find another impl : 
 fun navigateFirstTabWithClearStack() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment_nav)
        val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_nav) as NavHostFragment
        val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
        val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav)
        graph.startDestination = R.id.introFragment

        navController.graph = graph
    }
But do not understand exactly what it does, does it clear the stack ?

Comment: It should works, you dont need any link for it. `fragment_nav` is a fragment id? The id should look like `R.id.myFragment`.